# Python Overflow Error: iter index too large

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have a problem with big iterator in for loop in the code below. It generates floats by reading a string list containing numbers.

```
def float_generator(tekstowe):
        x = ''
        for c in tekstowe:
            if c != ' ':
                x += c
            else:
                out = float(x)
                x = ''
                yield(out)
```

I'm getting a **"OverflowError: iter index too large"**. I try to use really big iter numbers (like billions of values in a searched file). Is iter range somehow limited in for loops?

Using Python 2.7 64 bit. Thanks.

Comment: How big does `float(x)` get?

Comment: They are 0-255 valued and look a bit random like this:
25.75000000 0.340 22.33333397 0.667. I mean these are 4 example floats.

Comment: The answer is here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efac0438f42e03f0ece269ac8f1616bc6dc2d8bd/Objects/iterobject.c#L57 and here https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsSsize_t

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `tekstowe` is a sequence type that only implements `__getitem__`, not `__iter__`, so it's using the Python iterator wrapper that calls `__getitem__` with 0, then 1, 2, 3, etc., until `__getitem__` raises `IndexError`.

As an implementation detail, [Python 2.7.11 and higher limits the value of the index passed by the iterator wrapper to `LONG_MAX`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/iterobject.c#l57) (before 2.7.11, it wasn't bounds checked but it still used a `long` for index storage, so it would wrap and start indexing with negative values). This doesn't matter on most non-Windows 64 bit builds, where `LONG_MAX` is `2**63 - 1` (larger than you'd likely encounter), but on Windows, C `long`s remain 32 bit quantities even on 64 bit builds, so `LONG_MAX` remains `2**31 - 1`, which is low enough to be reached in human timescales.

Your options are:

1. Change the implementation of whatever class `tekstowe` is to give it a true `__iter__` method, so it doesn't get wrapped by the sequence iterator wrapper when you use it
2. Upgrade to Python 3.4+, ideally 3.5 (2.7.10/3.4.3 and below [lacks the check for overflow entirely](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.3/Objects/iterobject.c#l57), but this could mean wraparound causes infinite looping; [3.4.4/3.5.0 added the check, and they use a signed `size_t`, testing against `PY_SSIZE_T_MAX`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/iterobject.c#l57), which means it will not error until the index reaches `2**63 - 1` on any 64 bit build, Windows or otherwise)

The changes to add the overflow checks were made to resolve [Python bug #22939](https://bugs.python.org/issue22939); the type change (from `long` to `Py_ssize_t`) for the sequence iterator's index storage occurred in 3.4.0's release, resolving [Python bug #17932](https://bugs.python.org/issue17932).